# How to initiate (open and run) .ipynb files in Google colab from local terminal?

Tags: shell, google-colaboratory, godot

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-8M0vkX2d4&t=133s&ab_channel=RyanKrnwn) which points to this [Colab project](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbkV0c21GdUpvSkF4ZUVnb3ZuMGZ5NVdMdElZUXxBQ3Jtc0ttQ2N4N21JUFk4MHdDSnZ6NlMzd3c3ZlFaX0NzazQ2azRTcTQzRjZNaVJPLUxVLVZPQkZpYmNFTkt5dFJ3NDRwVUFaNHZxb0lUUnFmaV9RSmJHdlh2eVV6Wk53QzZOZmJER2ZWbG5YT2dlNjRIdjdiNA&q=https%3A%2F%2Fcolab.research.google.com%2Fdrive%2F1ZZlq1Uoo6zDz-HaPnh0Em-GjAo6jQrht%3Fusp%3Dsharing). It basically sets up an ssh connection with Google Colab and lets me control stuff from my terminal. I modified it a bit to automatically fill out the required fields and ready the ssh connection. The problem is that I still need to manually copy and paste the terminal command that it generates:

`ssh -p port_no user_name@ip_add`

I plan on saving this into a .sh file and download it by code and have my Godot project detect it from the local downloads folder and execute the .sh file.

All I need now is to find a way to start the Colab project **online** from my local pc. Is there any APIs that I'm not aware of? a shell command that loads and automatically run local .ipynb files into Google Colab?

I heard about [using Colab's local runtime](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) but that involves manually opening a web browser to begin with and I'm not so sure it would still use the VMs resources(THEM SWEET GPUs) at "local runtime".

I'd appreciate all the help that I could get, thanks in advance :)